# g2d.drawImage() and creating a BufferedImage slow

Tags: java

I've been making a game with the Java2D drawing tools, and I've encountered a bit of a framerate issue when it comes to the Graphics2D drawImage function. How my rendering currently works in my game is I call different rendering functions for different parts of the GUI in-game, and then I take the BufferedImages returned from those calls and merge them into larger images that I can then place onto the player's screen. This method, however, seemed to be incredibly slow, so I decided to try and work out why.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    g2d.drawImage(config.createCompatibleImage(1920, 1080), 0, 0, null);
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time + "ms");
```

This code here outputted 6197ms, clearly a very slow operation to do, but I still wanted to find out the problem. Was it the creation of the image, or the drawing it onto the screen?

So I ran this test:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
BufferedImage img = config.createCompatibleImage(1920, 1080);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time + "ms");
```

The output of that was only 62ms. Much, much faster. So, I concluded, it must be the creation of the BufferedImage that's the problem, but to be sure I ran one more test:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    config.createCompatibleImage(1920, 1080);
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time + "ms");
```

That gave me a result of 1980ms. Clearly, creating the image is only about a third of the total processing time. Where did those ~4000ms go between those three tests, and why did that happen?

As a side question, what is actually the best way of rendering a GUI such that it doesn't slow down the entire game?